# Python Regex - Remove special characters but preserve apostraphes

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to remove all special characters from some text, here is my regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+', re.UNICODE)
words = str(pattern.sub(' ', words))
```

Super simple, but unfortunately it is causing problems when using apostrophes (single quotes). For example, if I had the word "doesn't", this code is returning "doesn".

Is there any way of adapting this regex so that it doesn't remove apostrophes in instances like this?

**edit:** here is what I am after:

> ```
> doesn't this mean it -technically- works?
> ```

should be:

> doesn't this mean it technically works

Comment: First, you need to define what "special characters" are.

Comment: Everything removed by [\W]+. I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Maybe you want to do something more advanced than replacing non-ascii characters with space in the end? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> pattern=re.compile("[^\w']")
>>> pattern.sub(' ', "doesn't it rain today?")
"doesn't it rain today "
```

If underscores also should be filtered away:

```
>>> re.compile("[^\w']|_").sub(" ","doesn't this _technically_ means it works? naïve I am ...")
"doesn't this  technically  means it works  naïve I am    "
```

Comment: It is a little unclear from the question whether or not this is a requirement, but this will not remove underscores.

Comment: it gets more complicated if underscores also should be removed.  Maybe the a-zA-Z trick would be better.  I'll try to improve.

Comment: a-zA-Z won't work, as it won't cover non-ascii characters ... but I've fixed the problem anyway

Answer (score 1):

I was able to parse your sample into a list of words using this regex: `[a-z]*'?[a-z]+`.

Then you can just join the elements of the list back with a space.

Comment: [a-zA-Z] won't support international characters.

Comment: `>>> re.compile("[^a-zA-Z']").sub(" ","doesn't this -technically- means it works? naïve I am ...")`  => `"doesn't this  technically  means it works  na ve I am    "`

Comment: Good point. I was just doing a simple base-case as he said made it sound like he didn't need all the corner-cases covered.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
re.sub(r"[^\w' ]", "", "doesn't this mean it -technically- works?")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `([^\w']|_)+`?

Note that this won't work well for things like:

```
doesn't this mean it 'technically' works?
```

Which might not be exactly what you're after.